# Padding lost using <merge> tag with Custom Compound Component

Tags: android, merge, custom-controls, padding

Here's a [custom compound component](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound) that extends `RelativeLayout` and inflates a particular layout from xml:

```
public class MyCustomView extends RelativeLayout {
    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_custom_view, this);
        // ...
    }
}
```

The layout xml uses the `<merge>` tag (removes unnecessary layer from the view hierarchy, yada yada yada):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"  ... />

    <TextView  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"  ... />
    ...
</merge>
```

... and I use the custom view in other layouts like this:

```
<com.example.MyCustomView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dip" />
```

Everything within the custom view is immaculately laid out, but the **20dip padding** supposed to surround the entire thing  is **not** applied. It doesn't seem to work if I put it on the `<merge>` tag either. The lack of padding makes it look completely awful of course. Where am I supposed to put the `android:padding="20dip"` attribute to get it applied?

The easiest thing might just be to make my `MyCustomView` extend `FrameLayout`, and replace the `<merge>` tag with a `<RelativeLayout>` - but that sacrifices the whole 'keeping the view hierarchy shallow' thing that Romain Guy takes so seriously :)

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm tempted to just manually add padding to the view when I use it (within the greater layout), but was hoping to find a "dry"er solution.

Answer (score 8):

Now I use a workaround to set paddings programmatically. And looking for probably better solution.

```
// Inflate the view from the layout resource.
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from( context );
View root = li.inflate( R.layout.article_head, this, true );
int padding = convertDip2Pixels( context, 8 );
root.setPadding( padding, padding, padding, padding );        

public static int convertDip2Pixels( Context context, int dip ) {
    return (int)TypedValue.applyDimension( TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            dip, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics() );
```

Comment: This one worked for me. Instead of your little method, you could define a dimension resource on dimen.xml and use context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.desired_padding_id)